# Making chat app

Tags: android

I want to do a chat application and I found this code on GitHub : https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM. And author created a function to send a message which looks like this

```
public String sendHttpRequest(String params)
    {       
        URL url;
        String result = new String();
        try 
        {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            out.println(params);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(inputLine);              
            }
            in.close();         
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
        }

        return result;


    }
```

Where `private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.0.102/android-im/index.php";`

And also here he explained how to make it run
https://code.google.com/archive/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/

So, my question is that:   As I understood author sends all messages to his server and after this server sends them to user. So, if PC will be turned off server won't work and his chat won't work too, is it right? If yes, can somebody explain me how to do a chat app without server?

Thank you

Comment: Just host the server somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, seems like it requires a server to be online at all times. But that's how all modern chat applications on smartphones work (Telegram, Whatsapp, Threema, all google chats...). Without a server you would rely on the fact that both smartphones are online at the same time in order to establish a direct connection. This is a huge disadvantage and works against any power-saving features of the mobile OS. Also two parties can hardly communicate if they are always online at different times.

So essentially you need to decide for yourself whether you really want a peer-to-peer or a server-based chat. Just remember that even in case of P2P, you will have to figure out the IP addresses of the other chat clients. And then you'll probably have to use some sort of server, again.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a P2P chat implementation, you can use WIFI direct for that in Android. Checkout this code: https://github.com/life0fun/wifi-direct-chat

Usually the chat apps need to have a central server to receive the messages and send it to the correct nodes. That code you paste is that kind of implementation.